# What does Server Core App Compatibility (FOD) really do on Server 2019?

Tags: windows, windows-server-2019, windows-server-core

I am in the process of upgrading most of our Windows Servers to Windows Server 2019. Whenever I can I'll do a Servercore installation e.g for roles like:

- Domain Controller
- Web Server (IIS)
- File Server
- Print Services

etc.

In my office we develop a lot of C# Applications, that will run on some Application Servers. Some of these Applications have a GUI, others don't. I struggle to understand what - if any - type of GUI Application can run on Servercore, and if I can run my apps on Servercore

As far as I understand, Servercore should only be used for Servers that really have no need to have anything displayed in a GUI, just like the roles that I mentioned above, which can be managed through PowerShell or Remote GUI tools. Meaning our GUI C# applications should not run on Servercore.

However, I also read about [Server Core App Compatibility (FOD)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/get-started-19/install-fod-19) but I struggle to understand what this really does. Does this only add certain GUI applications for troubleshooting like `mmc.exe` and `Eventvwr.msc`, just like they describe in the docs, or is there more to it than they state in the docs?

They say:

> App Compatibility, a Feature on Demand for Server Core, significantly
> improves the app compatibility of the Windows Server Core installation
> option by including a subset of binaries and packages from Windows
> Server with Desktop Experience, without adding the Windows Server
> Desktop Experience graphical environment.

What does this really mean? Is this like an in-between, where I can use Servercore, but still run some smaller GUI Application? How do I find out if I can run GUI applications on a Servercore Server?

Also, there are these Windows Features. Do they differ from FOD?

```
Name                      DisplayName
----                      -----------
User-Interfaces-Infra     User interfaces and infrastructure
Server-Gui-Mgmt-Infra     Tools and infrastructure for graphical management
Server-Gui-Shell          Graphical shell for server
```

Comment: AFAIK it only add certain GUI applications

Answer (score 1):

App Compatibility allows a limited set of mmc.exe (.msc extension) applications. If you run **mmc.exe** from the cmd prompt and click **File->Add/Remove Snap-in**, you can see the list of included management tools.

You can also run them by themselves from the cmd prompt. Such as **cluadmin.msc** for Cluster Administrator, or **diskmgmt.msc** for Disk Manager, and my favorite, **devmgmt.msc** for Device Manager to easily install drivers (no more pnputil).

You can also run some Control Panel applets, such as Networking **ncpa.cpl** to view and edit network adapters.

You don't get a Start Menu, so I don't believe you can pin applications.

I only wish Windows Hyper-V Server 2019 included Hyper-V tools...

Comment: Server Core (and Hyper-V Server) expect that the normal operation of the server will be done entirely remotely using WinRM. So it's your workstation that needs to have Hyper-V Tools installed.

Comment: That worked great and all... until I suddenly realized my workstation continued to upgrade so far that I could no longer administer the Hyper-V cluster with it